# How does the limit of this complex fuction exist?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a pretty crude and uninformed question.

When dealing with complex numbers, how is it possible that

$$\lim_{z\to 0 } \frac{z + 3}{e^z-1} = 1$$

In human words;

I don't understand how the limit as $z$ goes to $0$ of the above function can exist at all. Surely it heads off to negative and positive infinity. Is this some complex analysis trickery?

Insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Random formatting tip: the limit will come out nicer if you use \lim{z \to 0} instead of just plain lim{z\to 0}.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I wondered what had gone wrong there.

Comment: Why do you think that limit equals $1?$

Comment: The limit is $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is actually part of a solution to another question on this site (that I could not respond to as I am a n00b).

Here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985161/show-that-function-fz-z23z-ez-1-can-be-expressed-as-a-power-series/1985423#1985423?newreg=9bc126e9833a4034845f6e043eeca597

Comment: I added an incorrect answer, but am unable to delete because it was accepted.

Comment: Copper.hat, the man himself! I'm actually glad to hear that because my head was in knots for hours ha. 

This is probably as good a place as any to ask, do you have any ideas about that initial queston?

Comment: Indeed the limit doesnt exists for $z$ being real.

Comment: @notaclue: I am repairing the answer as we speak (type). Bad limit taking on my part.

Comment: @notaclue: The other answer is correct now.